# How to select the $(window) of only a page

Tags: jquery

I have a console error (Safari web inspector) I suppose the problem comes from $(window). How to say only the window of a page?

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$("#altres .amunt").offset().top')
    (anonymous function) (general.js, line 6)
    dispatch (jquery-latest.js, line 4641)
    handle (jquery-latest.js, line 4309)
```

I have a html page that is completely empty. It has a ling to a general js file:

```
<script src="general.js"></script>
```

In general.js I only have:

```
$(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        var fletxa = $("#altres .amunt").offset().top;
        var finestra = $(window).scrollTop(); 

        if (finestra > fletxa) { 
            $("#altres .amunt").stop().animate({ top: 60 });
        } else {
            $("#altres .amunt").stop().animate( { top: 0} )
        };
    });

})
```

The code works well in the page that I have the divs divs #altres .amunt 
In the other pages that there is not that divs is normal to have an error. Should I have to use something to tell that it only affects to a specific page and not the others? I suppose the problem comes from $(window). How to say only the window of a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `#altres .amunt` does not exist, then `$("#altres .amunt").offset()` is `undefined`. Hence the exception, you want to read a property of something `undefined`.

You should check if the selector returns something, then act on the result, like

```
var selection = $("#altres .amunt").offset();
if (selection) {
    var fletxa = selection.top
}
```

By the way, if you do not need a piece of JavaScript code in certain pages, then *do not* include them. Or if you do include them, then use defensive coding at least, so check for preconditions, in this case, for the return value of the selector.

**Update:**

The quick (and dirty) solution

```
if ($("#altres .amunt").offset()) {
    $(window).scroll(function () { 
        // same as before
    });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain well. Please see the updated explanation

Comment: I am just learning. What I read in a tutorial says that it is better to have all the js code external and in one file

Comment: That may be true sometimes from a network latency standpoint. If you want to go this way, then you could put the whole scroll event handler in an `if` conditional block, and only define the event handler, when the `#altres` element exists.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no element with the id `alters`, then there is nothing to take the `offset` of, and you should expect an error when you try to.

Comment: Of course, but is it ok to have that kind or errors or should I do something about it? This will be a common problem if I have a general.js. Should I do anything to make that peace of code affect only to one page and not the others?

Comment: Errors, by definition, are not ok.  As @meskobalazs shows, this is an easy one to address.